# PDO drivers missing on Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7.2.4

Tags: php, pdo

I wanted to try the latest version of PHP on Kubuntu 16.04, since then, it seems I can't use pdo with mysql.

When I launch php, I have the following warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm running

```
PHP 7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Apr  5 2018 08:53:57) ( NTS )
```

I tried to fix with this solution : https://askubuntu.com/a/824505, but I've the same problem.

However, in the phpinfo, there's a driver found for PDO (mysql).
When I check a php -m, PDO and pdo_mysql are found.

In the **/usr/lib/php/20170718** and **/usr/lib/php/20151012** folder, there is a pdo_mysql.so.

I don't really know what else to try. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Check whether the line enabling `pdo.so` is above the line enabling `pdo_mysql.so`

Comment: I added pdo in the php.ini (extension=pdo), but nothing changed,

Comment: Do you use any included config files that might get parsed first?

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of, Idk how I can assure this tho.

Comment: Same issue with 18.04 LTS

Comment: I think this is related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/999999/php-with-pdo-mysql-in-ubuntu-16-04 where there is a solution

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.2-pdo
```

Comment: Hello, it tries to install php7.2-common when I run it. Since it's already installed, it does nothing.

Comment: I updated to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS today, same issue. Tried installing plenty of PHP DB related extensions, none satisfied PDO.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had updated from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, thus PHP 7.0 to 7.2.

Turns out PHP 7.0 was still (partly) installed, and was the active PHP-FPM handler for Apache.

Commands I used to resolve this: *(as root or via sudo)*

```
service php7.0-fpm stop
apt-get remove php7.0*
service php7.2-fpm restart
service apache2 restart
```

Be sure to copy any INI changes you made from `/etc/php/7.0` to `/etc/php/7.2` though.

Comment: I did an upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 and did not find this was the case, but the issue prevails.