# laravel php artisan serve error after uncommenting pdo_mysql in php.ini

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Thanks in advance.
I had the problem when i use `php artisan migrate`  in the terminal...This error was thrown:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL:
>   select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel
>   and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
>   at 
>   /home/nymeria/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
>       665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
>       666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
>       667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
>       668|         catch (Exception $e) {
>
> > 669|             throw new QueryException(
> >         670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> >         671|             );
> >         672|         }
> >         673|
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("could not find driver")
>         /home/nymeria/blog/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:31
>
> 2   PDOException::("could not find driver")
>         /home/nymeria/blog/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27

i searched and found out i should uncomment pdo.mysql extension in php.ini but when i did that i now am given this error(

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql'
>   (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql
>   (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so
>   (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol:
>   mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0 Laravel development server
>   started: http://127.0.0.1:8000 [Wed Jan  1 21:46:21 2020] PHP Warning:
>
> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried:
>   /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory),
>   /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so
>   (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol:
>   mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0

) whenever i want to use laravel or do anything at all in a laravel project.
oh and i should tell you that the pdo_mysql.so exists in the path shown in the error.

Comment: Did you set up the .env variables for your database?

Comment: this QA may helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49784177/6543507

Comment: @MEDZ Yes it is set up ,I checked.

Comment: @HoseinGhanbari No unfortunately it didn't. :(

Comment: can you post uncommented php.ini file fragment?

Comment: @colorgreen  here it is (`extension=pdo_mysql`)

Comment: Can you tell us OS and PHP version?

Comment: @colorgreen I'm on linux and i use php 7.2 .